# How to decode utf-16 encoded string in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, unicode, character-encoding, base64

I have a string which is encoded in utf-16.

I have to decode this string.

For utf-8 I use ***Base64.decode()*** method, but this method throws exception for utf-16 encoded string.

Could anyone help me in this in angularjs technology.

Below is the utf-16 encoded string:

```
//48AD8AeABtAGwAIAB2AGUAcgBzAGkAbwBuAD0AIgAxAC4AMAAiACAAZQBuAGMAbwBkAGkAbg
```

Base64.js is file is already there in my project. Below is the definition of decode method:

```
 var decode = function(a){
        return _decode(
            String(a).replace(/[-_]/g, function(m0) { return m0 == '-' ? '+' : '/' })
                .replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/]/g, '')
        );
    };
```

Comment: What is the expected output?  How/where is Base64.decode()  implemented & what error are you getting?  -  That string does not look readable in UTF16 LE/BE.

Comment: Is this meant to be some utf-16 encoded string that has been Base64-enocded or is it some Base64-encoded binary data where the Base64-string is UTF-16?

Comment: @piet.t : Hi, this is normal data which is written in english. Once we encode in Base64 using utf-16 then we get that data which i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @AlexK. String is readable if you try to check it here: https://www.base64decode.org/

Error I get is : "not a utf-8 string". I edited my question to show Base64.decode implementation.

Comment: The bytes that your base64 decode to do not seem to be UTF-16.  Can you add a test case that takes a string and returns that base64?